# Can I initialize a std::vector<bool> from uint8_t (or std::byte) range so that every bit in input is treated as a boolean?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I know that [`std::vector<bool>` is bad](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool), but I have a really nice use case for it.

I would like to do something like this:

```
uint8_t data [] = {7,32};
std::vector<bool> vb/*...*/ ;
// now vb is size of 8 vector with this values:
//   false, false, false, false, false, true,  true,  true, (7)
//   false, false, true, false, false,  false, false, false (32)
```

Note: I know I can manually disect every byte of input and make 8 inserts, but I am looking for something prebuilt in the standard

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be an use case for doing this?

Comment: `std::bitset` doesn't provide iterators for some reason, so I guess there's no smart way (without a loop) to do that.

Comment: @Luke serialization/deserialization of data that does not align on byte boundary, and references to serialized data(index is bit index).

Comment: @Luke I once wrote a prime number checker where all the primes were pre-computed and stored as a list of bytes used as bit flags.  But I did the bit manipulation myself and didn't try to utilize `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: An expressive way of doing this with standard library features may be to iterate over `data` and use an intermediate `std::bitset<8>` which can be constructed from an integer type and then reading out individual bits with its `operator[]` to push to `vb`. There is no `std::vector` constructor that can achieve this out-of-the-box. Though you could use the iterator based constructor by creating an iterator that wraps your array of bytes and which iterates the individual bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` is a poor choice here, because you are thinking about it in terms of its implementation rather than its behavior.... just avoid `vector<bool>`.

Use a `boost::dynamic_bitset` instead. Anecdotally I have personally found it to be far more performant anyway:

```
std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> data {7,32};
boost::dynamic_bitset<std::uint8_t> vb(rbegin(data), rend(data));
std::cout << vb; // 0000011100100000
```

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LK1xRuLYgx7CBtKk)

We have to reverse the input range because boost's dynamic bitset [appends](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#append1) to the end where the most significant bit is (typically the left side), rather than the right side.

Answer (score 4):

Using a [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) container is most certainly the best way to go - but if that's not an option, you could create an iterator type to populate your `vector<bool>` directly on construction.

Example:

```
struct biterator {
    using value_type = bool;
    using reference = bool;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = uint8_t*;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    biterator(const uint8_t* c) : curr(c), bit(1U<<7) {}
    biterator& operator++() { if(!(bit >>= 1)) { ++curr; bit = 1U<<7; } return *this; }
    bool operator*() const { return *curr & bit; }
    bool operator!=(const biterator& rhs) const { return curr != rhs.curr; }

private:
    const uint8_t* curr;
    uint8_t bit;
};
```

Usage:

```
uint8_t data [] = {7, 32};
    
std::vector<bool> vb(biterator(std::begin(data)), biterator(std::end(data)));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ta7fdn)

Comment: I like the idea of making a small iterator class. There's usually a lot of boilerplate involved, though to make it generic enough. I guess that's why you chose a `forward_iterator_tag` even though we could have a random access iterator if we really wanted. One question: what is the reasoning for marking the iterator trait 'reference' to be `bool`?

Comment: @AndyG Re: `forward_iterator_tag` Yes, I choose that to make it as short as possible. Lazy :) Re: `reference`, well, that's more lazyness. `std::iterator_traits<biterator>::reference foo = *iterator;` will not make `foo` a bit proxy object and changing `foo` won't do anything to the original data (which is `const` all the way in this iterator anyway). I'm not sure if I should have made it something else... `const bool` would perhaps be an option.

Answer (score 3):

The proposal for this is [P0237 Wording for fundamental bit manipulation
utilities](https://wg21.link/p0237):

```
#include <bit>
#include <cstdint>
std::uint8_t data [] = {7,32};
std::vector<bool> vb(
    std::bit_iterator(std::begin(data), 0)),
    std::bit_iterator(std::end(data), 0)));
```

There is an implementation of P0237 (and [N2050](https://wg21.link/n2050)) called [itsy](https://github.com/ThePhD/itsy_bitsy).